# LINQ to SQL 1:1 Insert

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am currently facing this problem. I have POCO manually mapped to my database tables via LINQ to SQL. I wish to place all these objects / tables under one context (treated as a transaction) so that if one fails in a transaction, all would roll back.

Now the problem I am facing is I have UserLogin and UserProfile (1 : 0 - 1 relationship). They are structured in a way where UserLogin's id is a PK and FK to UserProfile and the same goes for UserProfile. On UserLogin, it is set to automatically generate an identity with IsDBGenerated set to true. UserProfile on the other hand does not have IsDBGenerated.

UserProfile is set as an EntityRef in UserLogin and since they come from the same context, I set UserLogin.UserProfile = new UserProfile() when creating.

After assigning all properties, I did table.InsertOnSubmit(UserLogin) and context.SaveChanges().

This is where the real problem comes in. UserProfile's id remains as 0.

Can anyone help?

---

Sorry, I did not make myself clear. The SQL Server in use is MS SQL Server 2008.

The entity structure is like this,

UserLogin is mandatory upon signup while UserProfile is not, making it a 1 : 0 - 1 relationship. Therefore, it wouldn't be wise to have auto-increment on both tables.

UserProfile's PK is also an FK which references UserLogin.

@GertArnold, yes I did set UserProfile id = UserLogin id at asp.net code-behind but before the context is saved, UserLogin's id would remain 0 because at this point, I want both records to be added together and was wondering if Linq to Sql would have some way to resolve this. Since I've added Association attribute, by right Linq to Sql should recognize this dependency and add the id on submit, or at least, that's my wishful thinking.

In my UserProfile, I have this snippet:

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
public long id { get; set; }
private EntityRef<UserLogin> _login;
[Association(ThisKey = "id", Storage = "_login")]
public UserLogin UserLogin { get { return _login.Entity; } 
    set { _login.Entity = value; } }
```

In my UserLogin, I have the following snippet:

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
public long id { get; set; }
private EntityRef<UserProfile> _profile;
[Association(ThisKey = "id", Storage = "_profile")]
public UserProfile UserProfile { get { return _profile.Entity; } 
    set { _profile.Entity = value; } }
```

Lastly, in my code-behind, I have this:

```
UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
// All assigning here
login.UserProfile = new UserProfile();
// Assign here
login.userProfile.id = login.id;
```

At this point, both ids are zero because none of them has been inserted yet.

When I do context.SubmitChanges(), UserLogin's id will get incremented value but UserProfile's id will remain at 0. The reason why I want to wrap both in the same context and submit together is to avoid cases like say UserLogin is submitted, but UserProfile hits an error. So in my DB, there's a record for login but not profile, messing up my data.

Comment: What type of database are you using? Since UserProfile is a child record of UserLogin(at least it seems to me it is) why cant you just have UserProfile.Id be an AutoIncremting field in SqlServer, Add a sequence if its Oracle...?

Answer (score 2):

I had to read this question a number of times to understand what you are getting at. This line

> They are structured in a way where UserLogin's id is a PK and FK to UserProfile and the same goes for UserProfile

initially seemed to mean that `UserLogin` has a foreign key to `UserProfile`, *and* `UserProfile` has a foreign key to `UserLogin`. But I now think that what you're trying to do is use the same values for the PK in both tables; if I have `UserLoginId` = 123 and I then go create a profile, you want me to have `UserProfileId` 123.

Why are you doing this?  It's okay from a database perspective (although I'd argue not particularly beneficial, and somewhat confusing), but LINQ-to-SQL wants a primary key that it knows is the primary key for a single row, and not used as a primary key for any other table. And it wants a foreign key that isn't also a primary key.

The value 123 in the `UserProfile` table is really a Foreign Key to `UserLogin`, but not a primary key. It doesn't need to be the primary key and you're making things more confusing for LINQ-to-SQL by doing so. Let `UserProfile` have its own PK. Create a auto-incrementing identity, and change what you've got to be the foreign key back to `UserLogin`. All your problems will be resolved.

```
UserLogin
PK - UserLoginId int identity

UserProfile
PK - UserProfileId int identity
FK - UserLoginId int
```

In my experience, both LINQ-to-SQL & Entity Framework work best with simple surrogate primary keys - independent of everything else. Anything too tricky or non-standard can cause you more headaches than any perceived benefit or simplicity.

Comment: yea you got that right. That's precisely what I intend to do, to make UserProfile's id = UserLogin's id, skipping surrogate key. In EF, I was able to achieve this by playing around with fluent api but not in L2S. Sadly, this project is still stuck to L2S, which would give me a hard time should I decide to convert it to EF4.1 Anyway, I'll suggest your approach to my DBA and see how we go from there. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue (link below), if I am going to have to do this then I am going to lose the hard-coded one to one relationship in the relational database. This means it is possible to break that important constraint.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212290/linq-one-to-one-association-submitchanges

Comment: @andicrook Your question has been removed so I can't comment. But I don't entirely agree - you can still add a unique constraint on the foreign key column to ensure 1:1.